# Getting local PDF's URL using a Content Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension, content-script

When accessing pdfs for Google Chrome, the browser uses its own extension to read and show PDFs. I would like to get the URL from a local source file "file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/test%20extension/test.pdf" using a content script.

My goal is to eventually get the text of this PDF so that I can read through it, and the pdf.js library I am using requires the URL of the pdf.

On the chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html file, the below element holds this data.

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/test%20extension/test.pdf" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/e268f61a-7f6c-44ab-9218-7193dc73a783" headers="" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" javascript="allow" full-frame="">
```

I have embedded my content script as shown below in manifest.json:

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*.pdf"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
    ],
```

My content script has the following code which I believe should pull this URL:

```
var fileUrl = document.getElementById('plugin').src;
console.log('The file URL is : ' + fileUrl);
```

My goal is to get the console.log() above to return the fileUrl ("file:///C:/Users/Test/Desktop/test%20extension/test.pdf"). Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this? Is it possible that I am not calling my content script correctly?

Comment: Local files are special so you need an additional match pattern that starts with file:// and when your extension is installed from the web store the users will have to enable the file access toggle in extension's details on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the match pattern to "file://" did the trick!

Comment: the latest version of google chrome replaces the `src` attribute by an `internalid`. Any idea of how to get the URL of the PDF? see this entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197818/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-pdf-file-from-a-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @wOxxOm suggested, changing the "matches" pattern from

```
"matches": "*://*/*.pdf"
```

to

```
"matches": "file://*/*.pdf"
```

did the trick!!

Comment: Note that the suggestion was to _add_ that as a second pattern, not change it. You may get both permissions when you're developing the extension because already-granted permissions are remembered between reloads, but it won't persist if you reinstall it.