# how to get the URL of a PDF file from a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Last year I developed a google extension that worked on PDF files.
I used the following function in order to get the URL of the PDF file:

```
function getPDFUrl(): String {
    const e = document.body.firstElementChild;
    if (e.id != "plugin" || e.type != "application/pdf" || e.src == undefined)
        throw new Error("This does not look like a PDF document");
    return e.src;
}
```

Now, the latest version of Google Chrome does not provide the src attribue anymore.

```
<html>
  <body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);">
    <embed style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="3568AA495C01C5F2079A85384CEE54EE">
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the URL of the PDF file with the latest version of Google Chrome?

Comment: Is the extension available in chrome store?

Comment: no need. simple browse a pdf file, for instance http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf 
 then open the dev console, and type: `document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].type` -> it will tell that it is an `application/pdf`. The question is how to get the url. Before, the url was accessible by `document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].src`. Although I just realized that I can simply get the url by `window.location.href`. I don't know why I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently PDF is now viewed through an internal chrome extension `chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/`.

Aside from using `window.location.href` you can use `document.querySelector("embed").baseURI`